# Xcode 9 Continuous Integration with xcworkspace (CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode9-beta, xcode-server

I'm trying to set up a Continuous Integration Environment with the build in Xcode Server using Xcode9-beta. I successfully set up the server and running it on my local Mac. After setting up the server I created a Xcode Bot, but when I want to integrate the bot I get the error:

```
Assertion: Failed to build workspace BandDiscoverer with scheme <botname>.
```

Workspace BandDiscoverer.xcworkspace is in the [repository](https://github.com/Koen6095/FollowYourFavouriteArtists). I think it has something to do with the CocoaPods I use, but I can not find any solution.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: is your cocoapods in gitignore?

Comment: Currently I don't have a gitignore file yet

Comment: Do you have schemes in your project?

Comment: Yes I have, check the updated question.

Comment: The error is specifically say you dont have scheme named after your botname. What is your bot name? Change bot name to BandDiscoverer see if you still get errors.

Comment: You can specify scheme in your bot configuration. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html)

Comment: The botname is now the same as the scheme name, but I get still the error: Assertion: Failed to build workspace BandDiscoverer with scheme BandDiscoverer.